# react-quill adding extra line break on enter

Tags: reactjs, quill

I am using react-quill and swapped the wrapping from

to  however,the problem of having an extra line break exist.

this is my input and what i want it to look like when passed in the backend (qna maker)

```
<div>
  test1 <br>
  test2 <br>
  test3 <br>
</div>
```

but it becomes like this:

```
<div> test1 </div>
<div> test2 </div>
<div> test3 </div>
```

so when i pass it to the backend, it gets saved like this

test1\n\ntest2\n\ntest3 when i fact i only want to save it as test1\ntest2\ntest3

i have used this:

````````
 var Block = Quill.import('blots/block');
    Block.tagName = 'DIV';
    Quill.register(Block, true);
```````
 <ReactQuill
            value={this.props.value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            onBlur={this.setProps}
            modules={this.modules}
            formats={this.formats}
          />
````````

this is the markup being saved:

```
    <div>click <a href=\"https://twitter.com\" target=\"_blank\">here </a> for sample link test test testing test new line sample link <a href=\"https://www.google.com\" target=\"_blank\">here</a>.. and then <a href=\"https://www.facebook.com\" target=\"_blank\">here</a> test here</div>
<div>endtered value here</div>
<div><br></div>
<div><br></div>
<div>this is a new paragraphs</div>
<div>but this is just a new line</div>
```

and this is what it looks like in qnamaker

[image]